# kitchen list chef command issue

Tags: chef-infra

$ kitchen list

```
**>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
>>>>>> Message: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant --version ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: stdin is not a tty
---- End output of vagrant --version ----
Ran vagrant --version returned 1
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details**
```

kitchen.log file contents below

```
I, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.280284 #10484]  INFO -- Kitchen: -----> Starting Kitchen (v1.16.0)
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Exception-------
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: Kitchen::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant --version ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: stdin is not a tty
---- End output of vagrant --version ----
Ran vagrant --version returned 1
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----------------------
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/shell_out.rb:71:in `rescue in run_command'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/shell_out.rb:59:in `run_command'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.1.0/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb:434:in `run_command'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.1.0/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb:381:in `run'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.753844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.1.0/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb:455:in `run_silently'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.1.0/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb:521:in `vagrant_version'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.1.0/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb:182:in `verify_dependencies'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:43:in `for_plugin'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:233:in `new_driver'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:246:in `new_instance'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:142:in `block in build_instances'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:141:in `map'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:141:in `with_index'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:141:in `build_instances'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/config.rb:117:in `instances'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:112:in `filtered_instances'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:142:in `parse_subcommand'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.754844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/command/action.rb:35:in `block in call'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/command/action.rb:34:in `call'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:53:in `perform'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CLI>'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:334:in `invoke_task'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/bin/kitchen:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:171:in `with_friendly_errors'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.16.0/bin/kitchen:13:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/kitchen:22:in `load'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.755844 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/kitchen:22:in `<main>'
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.756344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----End Backtrace-----
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.756344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: ---Nested Exception---
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.756344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
E, [2017-07-21T14:50:03.756344 #10484] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant --version ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: stdin is not a tty
---- End output of vagrant --version ----
Ran vagrant --version returned 1
```

Using vagrant version 1.9.7

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: Does Vagrant work on its own, independent of Test Kitchen?

Comment: Yes,vagrant works independently

Comment: Same problem is reported in Chef mailing list. https://discourse.chef.io/t/test-kitchen-error-kitchen-shellout-shellcommandfailed/11249 I think this is bug caused by newer version of Vagrant as there is somebody who fixed this by uninstalling vagrant 1.9.x and installed vagrant 1.8.5

Comment: Submitted issue in kitchen-vagrant repo https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/issues/320